# ++ operator in R

Tags: r, operators, addition

This is really not so important but it would save some typing and make things look nicer occasionally. Is there anything like the C++ `++` operator in R? In other words is there an shorthand for `i<-i+1`? I don't really want to use it in loops which one should avoid in R anyway but I have a code with a list of matrices and want to increase or decrease numbers by one each time something happens (it is a simulation of a process), so I have to type something like `listname[[i]][j,k] <- listname[[i]][j,k] + 1`. Thanks.

Comment: Most useR do not miss ++, because it is an indicator that you are still writing C(++) or Java code. VectoRize!

Comment: You cannot vectorize everything. Like I mentioned, in the specific case where I use it, I cannot avoid changing things at a single index at a time because this represents changes in a (stochastic) jump process at particular times and the next state depends on the previous, so I need a loop over the time index and change things like this. I try to avoid loops and vectorize otherwise. R might not actually be the best language for this but I am writing it in it first mostly because it is easy to visualise things in it, probably not the best reason. I might later rewrite it in something else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can use `inc` from [Hmisc](https://cran.r-project.org/package=Hmisc).

```
inc(x) <- 1
```

The `dec` function does the reverse operation, it subtracts instead of add.

Comment: A small note: The function is actually `inc<-`. As a consequence, its help page is `?"inc<-"`.